# How to call async lamba expression with LINQ Select?

Tags: c#, lambda, async-await

Consider the following code...

```
List<myobject> items = dbItems.Select(x => ConvertDatabaseItem(x)).ToList();

private async Task<myobject> ConvertDatabaseItem(DataObjects.mydbobject x)
{
    var item = x.ToContract();
    await SetOtherInfo(item);
    return item;
}
```

This won't compile because we need to await the ConvertDatabaseItem...

```
List<myobject> items = dbItems.Select(async x => await ConvertDatabaseItem(x)).ToList();
```

however this will not work because we still need to await the async lamda expression otherwise its a compiler error (List< Task< myobject >> to List< myobject >).

```
List<myobject> items = dbItems.Select(await (async x => await ConvertDatabaseItem(x))).ToList();
```

However this gives a 'cannot await lamda expression'.

Am i missing something stupid here or is it not possible to do this?

Comment: How do you want to handle these tasks? Create and `await` them one at a time, or create all of them and then `await` them concurrently?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) method. Your solution will be like this:

```
var items = await Task.WhenAll(dbItems.Select(ConvertDatabaseItem));
```

Comment: This is the best solution for this specific case. Just note that it will return an array (`myobject[]`), not a `List<myobject>`

Comment: @GabrielLuci  Yes, the method returns `Task<TResult[]>`. This feature should be kept in mind. In general case it is better to work with `IEnumerable<TResult>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<TResult>`, or some other interfaces so that the caller is not dependent on a specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Didgeridoo...I wound up making the following call...

```
List<myobject> items = (await Task.WhenAll(dbItems.Select(async x =>
{
    var item = x.ToContract();
    await SetOtherInfo(..., item);
    return item;
}))).ToList();
```